# Python - socket.recv with str.find

Tags: python, string, sockets, character-encoding

I have the following Python code that reads text from the socket:

```
chunk = mySocket.recv(1024)
while (chunk.find("[footer]") < 0):
    chunk += mySocket.recv(1024)
```

Then I look for a substring containing non-English (cyrillic) characters:

```
chunk.find("Код активации")
```

Strangely enough, the `find` always returns `-1`.

But when I try save the result of download to file:

```
text_file = open("OutputResult.txt", "w")
text_file.write(chunk)
text_file.close()
```

The file really contains that text pattern I search for using `str.find`.

What am I doing wrong? Is it an issue with encoding or something else?

UPD:

Another important thing is that `print (chunk)` outputs text to the console in visibly wrong encoding. So I'm pretty sure that it's an encoding issue. The page I'm downloading from is in "windows-1251".

Comment: Could you please post some examples of the text you are searching for? Or some output of `print` command

Comment: @SharpAffair I corrected the `while` internal block indentation (and there was missing `:` too). Did you try to test presence of `"[footer]"` by `while "[footer]" not in chunk:`?

Comment: @phyrox, just added samples to the question.

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky, just tried that - no noticeable difference. It still doesn't find the required text.

Comment: What encoding are you using at the top of your .py file?

Comment: @Gerrat, # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @Gerrat, however, changing that to "# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-" didn't fix it.

Comment: Maybe the dash is an emdash.